# Find coordinate value inside the polygon after increasing the area of polygon

Tags: math, linear-algebra

Let's say we have this rectangle/square ABCD and a point E defined inside it.

[image: -a]

Now we increase the area of this rectangle/square and now it's like this:

A -> A`, B -> B`, C -> C`, D -> D`

[image]

Here what will be the value of E`(E -> E` = ?)

Comment: Is my answer unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve relative position inside rectangle, you have to provide the same ratio of every coordinate against width and height as before resize

```
(new_x - new_a_x) / (new_b_x - new_a_x) = (x - a_x) / (b_x - a_x)
```

so

```
new_x  = new_a_x + (new_b_x - new_a_x) * (x - a_x) / (b_x - a_x)
```

and similar for `new_y`

```
new_y  = new_a_y + (new_d_y - new_a_y) * (y - a_y) / (d_y - a_y)
```